# Convert specific rows to header and specific rows to header values SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, toad

I have below data in Toad SQL Database table. Let us say the table name to be tblSample.

```
ID     NAME   COVERMONTH  EFFECTIVEDATE  TERMDATE  PAIDAMOUNT  EARNEDAMOUNT
1546871 SAMPLE1    202001   1-Aug-14     31-Dec-99       5122.12     5111.02  
1065418 SAMPLE2    202001   1-Jan-15     31-Dec-99           0           0
1546871 SAMPLE1    202002   1-Aug-14     31-Dec-99        5122.12     5111.02  
1065418 SAMPLE2    202002   1-Jan-15     31-Dec-99        3211.21     3211.21
```

In the above data, I have data for 2 project ID's. In actual case the count of project ID's will be dynamic

NOTE: COVERMONTH will be dynamic values. They change month over month.

Desired output is shown below

```
ID    NAME    EFFECTIVEDATE    TERMDATE    202001    202002   202003 --- all the rows are completed
1546871 SAMPLE1   1-Aug-14      31-Dec-99  5122.12   5111.02   5122.12 ------
1065418 SAMPLE2   1-Jan-15      31-Dec-99      0     3211.21   3012.12 ------
```

In simple words, I need to make COVERMONTH as column header and EARNEDAMOUNT as its row value for a particular ID.

In the Sample table ID, NAME , EFFECTIVEDATE, TERMDATE are same for a particular ID but PAIDAMOUNT and EARNEDAMOUNT varies for month over month.

Any help in getting the end result is kindly appreciated.

Comment: This just looks like a (dynamic) pivot. What have you tried, why didn't it work? What was wrong with [all the other questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+dynamic+pivot+sql+server) with answers that show you how to do this?

Comment: @Dale K ..I am using Toad for Sql Server.

Comment: @Larnu.. I got all the unique ID's to temp table and then iterated over the actual table with unique ID in where contion using CURSOR. But I failed while using CURSOR.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation, if you know the months that you want:

```
select ID, NAME, EFFECTIVEDATE, TERMDATE,
       sum(case when COVERMONTH = 202001 then EARNEDAMOUNT end) as ea_202001,
       sum(case when COVERMONTH = 202002 then EARNEDAMOUNT end) as ea_202002,
       . . .
from t
group by ID, NAME, EFFECTIVEDATE, TERMDATE
```

Comment: How can I pass my COVERMONTH dynamically since those values change every month. I cannot hardcode them. Please suggest.

Comment: @shyam . . . Your question was not clear about whether or not the cover months need to be dynamic -- that is why I have "if you know the months you want".  To handle dynamic columns, you need to write dynamic SQL.  That is much more complicated and database-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

> @COVERMONTH1 and @COVERMONTH2 is input

```
Create Proc usp_myproject
     @COVERMONTH1 int
    ,@COVERMONTH2 int
AS
    Set nocount on

    Select ID, [NAME], EFFECTIVEDATE, TERMDATE,
           sum(case when COVERMONTH = @COVERMONTH1 then EARNEDAMOUNT end) as COVERMONTH_One,
           sum(case when COVERMONTH = @COVERMONTH2 then EARNEDAMOUNT end) as COVERMONTH_Two
    From t
    Group by ID, NAME, EFFECTIVEDATE, TERMDATE
```